# ¿Cómo llamar a una api de genexus desde postman?

Tags: genexus, postman, jsonobject

Recientemente he creado una procedimiento desde donde se puede consumir una api en genexus la api funciona si lo llamo desde otro procedimiento, le he puesto en las propiedades **rest protocol a true** el procedimiento recibe estos parámetros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al intentar ejecutarlo desde postman recibo un error que dice **Unrecognized field**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es la primera vez que hago este tipo de integraciones, agradezco de antemano su ayuda!!!

Comment: Creo que es más fácil si exportas el YAML con la definición del servicio que creaste, con eso lo importas a postman y ese amigo te ayuda a armar la petición más fácil https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?50054,Calling+rest+API+Using+Postman+app

Comment: Gracias @Alfabravo Funcionó con esta documentación https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?50054,Calling+rest+API+Using+Postman+app ahora ya puedo llamarlo desde postman, ahora lo estoy tratando de llamar desde un web panel que está en otro proyecto en otra carpeta y en otro servidor local 8081 distinto al de 8080 bueno solo para seguir aprendiendo quería intentarlo pero aún no lo logro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día.

Desde postman los nombres de los parámetros van sin la llave & y por mas que el valor sea numérico agrégalo entre comillas, serian por ejemplo:
"HPiLAnio": 2022,
"HPiLMes": 4,

Creo que solo con eso diferente te debería funcionar.